# Inspecting an intermediate Rxjs result before handling error

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using Observables for handling HTTP Requests in Angular and have a question regarding error handling. The endpoint in question returns a boolean value depending on the success of the operation done. However, a `false` value (as far as I know) will *not* trigger the error handler.

Here is an example:

```
this.myService.myMethod(user.id)
    .subscribe(
        result => {
            if (result) {
                // ... do some things
                return;
            }
            
            // result is false here, so I want to trigger the error handler
            return throwError({});
        },
        error => {
            // handle the error
            // I want this to happen for non-200 responses and 200 responses with a false result
        }
    )
);
```

Is this the most pragmatic way of handling an error like this? I have tried the above and I notice that on `throwError` the error handler is not triggered.

Comment: With regards to HTTP requests, a 200 is not an error.  If the same error handling should happen in both cases (a 200 with false or a non-200), then I would suggest extracting that error handling into another method, and call that method from both places.

Comment: What I meant is that I'd like the logic I have written to trigger the error handler even when the response is a 200 (but the data is falsy).

Comment: Right, but what I am saying is that you are attempting to inject an error into the logic to make other logic happen, rather than just calling the desired logic, which you could do if it was an extracted method.

Comment: I don't see there being anything wrong with throwing an exception in this manner, but I'd advise putting the logic in a `pipe` and not in callbacks to `subscribe`. I'm compiling an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you avoid putting any logic in `subscribe` callbacks and put everything into a `pipe`. As for the approach, here is what I would suggest:

```js
this.myService.myMethod(user.id).pipe(
  mergeMap(result => result ? of(result) : throwError('My error!')),
  tap(result => doStuff()),
  catchError(error => {
    handleError(error);
    return EMPTY;
  }
  )
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tap` to throw an error. This error will be caught and propagated as an error notification.

```ts
this.myService.myMethod(user.id).pipe(
  tap(result => { 
    if(!result) throw result
  })
).subscribe(
  result => {
    // do some things
  },
  error => {
    // handle the error
  }
);
```

Comment: It’s generally best to avoid putting logic in subscribe callbacks. Keeping everything in the pipe makes things much more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: @WillAlexander It depends on what you do. Doing `o$.pipe(tap(v => doStuff(v))).subscribe()` instead of `o$.subscribe(v => doStuff(v))` is pretty pointless in my opinion. But moving the error handling into `this.myService.myMethod` would be advisable.

Comment: In order to maintain code style across an entire app, the best practice is to put everything in the pipe. That way, when the day comes where you have to add functionality, you don't have to refactor everything. Also, it is often best to decentralize error handling to keep things clean, so putting it in the service method is often not the best option.

Comment: @WillAlexander How does decentralizing error handling keep your code clean? You'll just end up with repeating the same or similar error handling all over your app.

Comment: If your error handling is always the same, then yes, put it in the service. However, if you have multiple feature modules or areas of the app leveraging the same service, allowing each to independently handle its errors gives you the best modularity. As with everything, it’s a trade off. When I jump into a client’s code, I’m a lot happier if I don’t have to constantly jump from file to file. Being able to follow a pipe and have all the information I need is a huge productivity gain during maintenance.